# Apache log4j 1.2.17 missing artifact error on pom.xml maven

Tags: maven, selenium, log4j, pom.xml

I added the apache log4j 1.2.17 dependency in my pom.xml maven project. After saving the changes I have a lot of errors which are mostly "missing artifacts error". What should I do to fix this error?

[image]

This is the dependency I used from the maven repository
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.17

I want to use Log4j as my logging framework for my selenium testing

Answer (score 0):

Update your maven project by right click on it and choose options MAVEN>UPDATE PROJECT. It would resolve your problem.

[image: How to update Maven project?]

If still you are getting same problem then use `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` to regenerate the eclipse project files -- hope that sorts you.

Comment: Hi, I can still see the errors. I updated the project and I use m2 eclipse plugin and I selected the project and run Maven clean. What else can I do about this? Been searching this for a solution to this but I can't find an answer

Comment: `<dependency>
 <groupId>log4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>`